# Is there a simple way to initialize a variable inside of an XML file?

Tags: xml, global-variables

Is there a simple way to initialize a variable inside of an XML file, with variables defined in an external plain text file?

For example:

Inside of the external plain text file:

dbname="somedbname"

dburl="10.10.10.20:3306"

Inside of the XML file:

<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://{##dburl}/{##dbname}?autoreconnect=true&amp;interactiveClient=true">

--OR--

<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://{$dburl}/{$dbname}?autoreconnect=true&amp;interactiveClient=true">

I really need this to work for a special new project, that will form the base for multiple internal projects, going forward.

I can easily do this from a typical shell script, by simply sourcing in the external text file.

Is there some way to easily do this inside of an XML file?

Remember, to make this work, I must be able to source the variables from an external plain text file.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use entities such as `&dbname;` but it's a clumsy mechanism because they have to be declared in a DTD.

A better approach is probably XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet .....>

<xsl:param name="dbname"/>
<xsl:param name="dburl"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <parameter-doc>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://{$dburl}/{$dbname}?autoreconnect=true&amp;interactiveClient=true">
  </parameter-doc>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Run this stylesheet (on any source document, or in 2.0+ without a source document) and it will spit out the parameter document with the variables expanded.

Alternatively (in response to your comments), if you want to keep the XML file easy to edit, you can write a stylesheet that takes the XML configuration file and inserts the values of environment variables, something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"...>

<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:template match="@*[contains(., '{$')]">
  <xsl:variable name="regex">\{\$([a-z]+)\}</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:attribute name="name(.)">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="{$regex}">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="environment-variable(regex-group(1))"/>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Will this style sheet allow me to pickup the environment variables from an external flat text file?

Comment: I want to deliver generic code to all servers, regardless of environment.  Then, any environment variables that are server, dev, qa, prod, or customer specific, will always read what they need to differentiate each deployment, based on what is in the external configuration file.  There could be numerous different people, with different skill levels, who need to populate this external configuration file.  I need to keep the content of this external configuration file as simple as possible, using the delivered code to read from this external file.

Comment: I can already do this with numerous other scripts and even programs, but the XML document seems to be a whole 'nother animal.

Comment: You can pick up environment variables from a stylesheet in XSLT 3.0, but not in earlier versions.